# Iterative data gathering from server

Tags: java, web-services

I'm building a web server and client which I will use on a Raspberry Pi. The server is written in Python and every time a client connects to it, it will return data to the client. This is working well and when I access the server through my browser, I see the correct data and when I refresh the page I get new data, so that is working.

The problem is that I'm now writing a client in Java to access the server and collect the data. The reason I use here Java is that I'm more experienced in it and I find building a GUI more convenient; I use python on the raspberry pi because it offers me a simpler way of interacting with the hardware.
The java client code I have is this:

```
while (true) {
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.37", 9315);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    try {
        System.out.println("Getting");
        out.write("GIMME DATA!");
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("receiving");
        String data;
        while ((data = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Line: " + data);
        }
        socket.close();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This all works well, but I want to take the initial 3 objects out of the while loop (and obviously not close the connection). When I do that, I only can access the server once (it will give me the correct data) and on the second run `in.readling()` will return null which is weird. It seems that the inputstream only has the data from the initial run and no more bytes are written to it. To be clear, when putting the initial 3 objects IN the while loop, everything works well.

How can I take the objects out of the loop? It seems wasteful, time consuming and possibly memory consuming to create them every time...

Comment: I just looked at this because it has a python tag; Java is not my favorite blend, but I would guess that `in` reaches eof in the first iteration and that makes the `readLine` invocation in the second and subsequent calls unconditionally return null..

Answer (score -1):

Once you have reached to end of the file or BufferedReader reached to end of data, then how can it print again data from beginning.  For example :

```
     int i = 0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\data.txt")));
    while (true) {

        String data = "";
        while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(" data :" + data);
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        i++;
        if (i == 2) {
            break;
        }
    }
    br.close();
```

In the above program, br reached to end of file, then it cannot point to the beginning. You have to create BufferedReder object every time when you enter while loop.

Comment: I tried this in my code by initializing the socket and out objects before the while loop and the buffered reading IN the while loop, but this still doesn't work. It only retrieves data on the first iteration and on subsequent iterations it doesn't retrieve the data: in.readLine() returns null there

Comment: You have to create object of BufferedReader in first line in while loop, and close it in last line while exiting the loop.

Comment: It then gives me an error telling that the socket has been closed (even though I only closed the bufferedreader). I think I can only fix it by creating a new socket object on each iteration...

Comment: Closing buffered reader close all other wrapped streams. So, instead of BufferedReader use DataOutputStream/DataInputStream.

Comment: Example: http://www.javatpoint.com/socket-programming  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm